# SparkSQL Total up amount based on a bucket-index

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, count, aggregation

I'm trying to write a SparkSQL 2.0 query to total up the amount based on a bucket_index.

My table looks like:

```
log_date, bucket_index, amount
2022-11-18, 1, 1
2022-11-18, 2, 1
2022-11-18, 2, 1
2022-11-18, 3, 1
2022-11-18, 3, 1
```

My query so far:

```
select log_date, count(bucket_index)
from data_table
group by bucket_index, amount
order by bucket_index, amount
```

I want it to look like:

```
bucket_index, amount
1, 1
2, 2
3, 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to group by `bucket_index` and sum the `amount`s in each bucket.

This translates easily to SQL:

```sql
SELECT bucket_index, SUM(amount) AS total
FROM data_table
GROUP BY bucket_index
```

You may also want to include other bucket statistics, and you can achieve it by adding more aggregations:

```sql
SELECT bucket_index,
       SUM(amount)   AS total,
       COUNT(*)      AS count,
       MIN(log_date) AS first_date_in_bucket,
       MAX(log_date) AS last_date_in_bucket
FROM data_table
GROUP BY bucket_index
```